# Not receiving emails after delay in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the past, I placed the following code snippet in function.php to speed up the checkout process in WooCommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails', '__return_true' );
```

However, recently I have not been receiving emails when there are new orders. After removing the above code snippet, everything works fine, but it slows down the checkout process by 20-30 seconds. Upon investigation, I found the error here:
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null in /woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php:34

```
$order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' )
```

Is there a way to delay email processing to speed up the checkout process without causing this error? Or how can I fix the error mentioned above?

Comment: You may want to check that your ActionScheduler is running correctly, check the WooCommerce status pages for more information

Comment: I have checked the ActionScheduler, everything is working fine. However, after a new order is placed, no email notifications are being sent.

Comment: You might want to install a plugin "WP Mail Logging", check that you get a copy of the email there.

Comment: Next step, try to set up mailgun as your mail delivery agent, and that will give you a lot more info.